# how to disable validation for a field

Tags: parsley.js

In parsley2, is there no way to disable validation for a field? i.e. I have a `<select>`-control, which will always return a value and needs to further validation. Parsley's unneeded error-list, however, ruins my formatting - so I'd like to disable validation complately for that field. I know I could assign a different error-container, but that feels 'unclean'...

I tried to add `data-parsley-exclude="select"` to the form, but that has no effect. *(It was a wild guess anyway...)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- exclude the select in the Parsley options you are passing to your form
- deactivate UI for this particular select (see UI part of the doc)

You could think for a more "clean" exclusion method and submit it in a PR.

Best

Comment: Thanks Guillaume, I tried to exclude it with `data-parsley-exclude="select"`, but that did not work. How could I use that option to disable validation of a specific field? (Yes, I read the doc - but either it is unclear or I missed the point...)

Comment: Wow - years later I come back to my own question and find out what I missed then: `data-parsley-excluded=true` seemed to do the job :)

Comment: @MBaas Wow, years later you still use Parsley ;)

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing like it ;-). I like how I can drive the whole validation througjndata-attributes! Though the one thing I dearly miss would be a feature to validate a singke field. I finally wrote a cover-fn to do that...

Answer (score 3):

I've found some issues with this method that I'm still trying to fix, so your mileage may vary with what I'm about to show you.

You can deactivate parsley validation, remove the `required` attribute for the element that you want to disable validation for, and then reactivate Parsley.

First, let's assume you bound Parsley validation to your form like so:

```
$('#my-form').parsley({
  //options
});
```

The element `#my-reg-form` is your `<form>`, just to be clear.

Your "refresh" of Parsley validation code would look something like:

```
// Deactivate Parsley validation
$('#my-form').parsley().destroy();

// Make your field not required, thus disabling validation for it
$('#disabled-select').removeAttr('required');

// Reactivate Parsley validation
$('#my-form').parsley({
   //options
});
```

This can also be done in reverse, if you want to make that field a required field again.

```
// Deactivate Parsley validation
$('#my-form').parsley().destroy();

// Make your field required by adding the required attribute back to the element
$('#disabled-select').attr('required', '');

// Reactivate Parsley validation
$('#my-form').parsley({
   //options
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this old, but I actually still use Parsley v1 and I typically use the

`$('#form').parsley('validate')`

...command to validate a form in a custom way.

I needed to exclude a field that has its own custom validation and I used Parsley's `removeItem` call right before I called the above command. This removes the field from the validation cycle:

`$('#form').parsley('removeItem', '#someInput');`

Answer (score 0):

For Parsley V2 -- add `data-parsley-excluded=true` to your element.

REF:
https://parsleyjs.org/doc/

Comment: Right. As I found out myself and mentioned in my reply to Guillaume's accepted answer :)

Answer (score -1):

set **data-parsley-required** to false, that also work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks Basit, nice try - but I had found that already and mentioned it in a comment below the accepted answer.